# Fields calculating only after a refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser

I apologize in advance for what I assume is a very basic question, but I am very new to scripting and would like to ask for some advice on a problem I am having.

Essentially I am creating a website that should sum the dollar amounts of two fields based on hours worked and return a total dollar amount. One of the fields has a fixed dollar amount and the other is a variable.

As far as I can tell the code should be working, but the field that should be user generated (esceptionalRate) seems to calculate correctly only  after a page refresh, and then only on firefox... instead of automatically updating the total value when a change is made to the user field

code as follows:

```
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function () {

var standardRate = 110;
var exceptionalRate = $("#ex_rate").val();

var standardEntry = 0;
var exceptionalEntry = 0;

var totalVal = 0;

$("#Standard").on("change",function(){
  standardEntry = $(this).val() * standardRate;
  totalVal = standardEntry + exceptionalEntry;
  $("#Amount").val(totalVal);
});

$("#Exceptional").on("change",function(){
  exceptionalEntry = $(this).val() * exceptionalRate;
  totalVal = standardEntry + exceptionalEntry ;
  $("#Amount").val(totalVal);
});

</script>
```

and here's the HTML side:

```
    <input name="Standard" type="number" step="any" value="0" id="Standard" size="10" />

    <input type="text" size="10" name="ex_rate" id="ex_rate" />

    <input name="Exceptional" type="number" step="any" value="0" id="Exceptional" size="10" />

    <td valign="top" nowrap="nowrap"><font size="2">Total Amount Requested </font></td>
<td><input name="Amount" type="text" id="Amount" size="35"/></td>
```

thanks in advance for all your wisdom and knowledge.

Comment: What does it do the rest of the time? (I'm assuming you have included jQuery on your page at some point.)

Comment: Side note, don't use `<font size="2">`. Use CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten to close the `$(document).ready` function

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).on("change", "#Standard", function(){
```

And:

```
$(document).on("change", "#Exceptional", function(){
```

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to break something... neither field then is able to calculate anything for some inexplicable reason

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `exceptionalRate` variable is out of the scope of your calculation, and only gets set to the initial value upon the page loading. You need to move it within the change handler:

```
$("#Exceptional").on("change",function(){
  exceptionalRate = $("#ex_rate").val();
  exceptionalEntry = $(this).val() * exceptionalRate;
  totalVal = standardEntry + exceptionalEntry ;
  $("#Amount").val(totalVal);
});
```

Comment: While this does help (it can differentiate between different values in the ex_rate field) it still does not work on browsers other than firefox... and it also seems to kill the final totalVal sum at the end.